# IIS Registration with websetup

Tags: vb.net, web

I had 4 different projects in single web solution. I want to give IIS registration each of them separately through single web setup(msi). how can i achieve this? please anybody help me.

Answer (score 0):

use Wix, we have been doing this in our project
http://wix.sourceforge.net/index.html

You need to google around on it, its hard to start on with Wix so need some patience on it and just keep trying and you will succeed.

wix is very flexible and robust.